# Getting all the rows each time querying KTable with KSql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

i would like to make rest api call to Kafka using Ksql and each time to get all the rows from the Ktable. 
What is the best way to get all the rows from KTable?

when i produce message (exp: Key = '1') to the topic that Ktable is listening to, i receive just the aggregation on the given key. What query should i make with each request to the web service to read all the rows from the table?

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'` before your SELECT query statement.